# Console.SetIn() immediately closes console application

Tags: c#

I just learned about the Console.SetIn() function and tried it out. It keeps closing my console application immediately even though I end my main method with a Console.ReadLine().

This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.SetIn(new StreamReader("example.txt"));
        string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        int L = int.Parse(input[0]);
        int m = int.Parse(input[1]);
        string[] lelijk = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

And this is in example.txt:

```
40 0
Hello world!
```

Comment: Oh come on. You specified that your input should no longer come from the user, but from a file, and you're then surprised that the program no longer waits for input from the user?

Comment: When setting the `In`-location of your console, from where do you expect `ReadLine` read characters? You should read about [reading text-files](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file). I doubt you want to set the `In`.

Comment: It's better to forget again about this function, because it's rarely useful (and certainly not for reading files).

Comment: If you want to test input redirection then use Project > Properties > Debug tab, "Command line arguments" = `< example.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Use this at the end of the main. It will wait for a key press, and after it the console will closed.